# How to address multiple content providers?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I created two content providers that work on two different tables of the same SQLite database. They share a single instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` as [described in the post of Ali Serghini](http://devserghini.blogspot.de/2010/11/android-sqliteopenhelper-and-multiple.html). Each content provider is registered in `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows.

```
<provider
    android:name=".contentprovider.PostsContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.myapp.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:multiprocess="true" >
</provider>
<provider
    android:name=".contentprovider.CommentsContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.myapp.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:multiprocess="true" >
</provider>
```

Each content provider defines the needed content URIs and supplies an `UriMatcher`.

```
public class PostsProvider extends BaseContentProvider {

    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();
    private static final int POSTS = 100;
    private static final int POST_ID = 101;

    private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
        final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        final String authority = CustomContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;
        matcher.addURI(authority, DatabaseProperties.TABLE_NAME_POSTS, POSTS);
        matcher.addURI(authority, DatabaseProperties.TABLE_NAME_POSTS + "/#", POST_ID);
        return matcher;
    }
```

...

```
public class CommentsProvider extends BaseContentProvider {

    protected static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();
    protected static final int COMMENTS = 200;
    protected static final int COMMENT_ID = 201;

    private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
        final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        final String authority = CustomContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;
        matcher.addURI(authority, DatabaseProperties.TABLE_NAME_COMMENTS, COMMENTS);
        matcher.addURI(authority, DatabaseProperties.TABLE_NAME_COMMENTS + "/#", COMMENT_ID);
        return matcher;
    }
```

When I invoke the content resolver to insert posts, the `PostsContentProvider` is targeted. When I try to insert comments, however, the content resolver does **not** refer to the `CommentsContentProvider` as expected, but calls upon the `PostsContentProvider`. The result is the following exception which I throw in the `PostsContentProvider`.

```
UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://com.example.myapp.provider/comments
```

Is it possible to output all available content URIs currently registered with an content provider?

Comment: "I created two content providers that work on two different tables of the same SQLite database" -- why not use one `ContentProvider` that works "on two different tables of the same SQLite database"? That's what the path is for in the `Uri`, to allow you to distinguish between different tables or the like.

Comment: @CommonsWare Because I plan to use a `SyncAdapter` in the future and I heard that a provider's data can only be synced if it is a separate provider. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am happy to read any documentation on that topic.

Comment: Ah, OK. I haven't played with `SyncAdapter` yet. I would be somewhat surprised by the limitation you cite, but I have no knowledge of whether that limitation exists or not. Sorry!

Comment: No offense taken. The `SyncAdapter` is a mysterious thing still to me. I researched quite a while but I am still not sure whether I can [use a `SyncAdapter` to sync "normal" data with a REST backend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906172/synchronize-android-client-and-rest-server).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `android:authorities` needs to be unique for each content provider. The documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html)
quoted from doc

> The content: scheme identifies the data as belonging to a content
>   provider and the authority (com.example.project.healthcareprovider)
>   identifies the particular provider. The authority therefore must be
>   unique.

Comment: I saw this one coming by the time I found this post, but thank you for confirming. Strangely enough, the documentation currently does not mention anymore that the name should be unique?

Comment: Ten years later, confirming that the docs still don't mention that the authorities should be unique. However, it does say (in an example) "The authority `com.example.project.healthcareprovider` identifies the provider itself," which taken at face value, suggests that the authority has to be unique, in order to uniquely identify the provider.